# Issue while taking a series of character as input and converting the case in C

Tags: c, character

Hey I am beginner in programming i need help to solve this problem.
I am writing a code to input a character and convert it into the opposite case (if it is in lower case then convert to upper case and vice-versa), the code is supposed to terminate when user enters semicolon (;).

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    /* code */
    char c;
    while(1)
    {
        c=getchar();
        if(c<97)
        {
            printf("%c",c+32);
        }
        if(c>=97)
        {
            printf("%c",c-32);
        }
        if(c == ';')
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output which i am getting:

```
t
T*
*H
h*
*j
J*
*;
[
```

Issue - After entering the first character, when i press enter it gets converted into upper case which is fine, but i am also getting an asterisk (*). Again to input next character , when i am pressing enter i am getting *. Also, when i am pressing ; the program do terminates but it prints "[" .
Can you please help me with this, not sure about why the * and [ are coming in the O/P.

Expected output:

```
t
T
H
h
j
J
;
```

Comment: Side note: You can use the standard library function [`islower`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/islower) in order to determine whether a character is a lower-case alphabetical character. And you can use [`isupper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isupper) in order to determine whether a character is an upper-case alphabetical character. You can use the functions [`tolower`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/tolower) and [`toupper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/toupper) for converting the case.

Comment: Continuation of side note: The function [`isalpha`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isalpha) may also be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason of getting `*` character in output is that after entering a character you must be pressing `ENTER` key, that means, there are two characters in input buffer - the character you have entered followed by `\n` character. The character you have entered is converted to opposite case and printed and when `getchar()` is called again it read `\n` character from input buffer.

The decimal ascii value of `\n` character is `10`. The `if` condition `(c<97)` evaluate to `true` and `32` is added to `10` which results in `42` which is decimal ascii value of `*` character. Hence, you are getting `*` character in output.

When you enter `;` character, decimal ASCII of `;` is `59`, the `if` condition `(c<97)` evaluate to `true` and `32` is added to `59` which results in `91` and ASCII character of decimal value `91` is `[`. Hence, you are getting `[` character when entering `;`.

Instead of just checking `if(c<97)` for upper case, change it to `if ((c>=65) && (c<=90))`. Same is for lower case character, instead of checking `if(c>=97)`, change it to `if ((c>=97) && (c<=122))`.

Note that return type of `getchar()` is `int` and not `char`. So, the type of `c` should be `int`:

```
int c;   // changed type from char to int
while(1)
{
    c = getchar();
......
```

You should also add the check for `EOF` because `getchar()` returns `EOF` on failure. That said, you can have `while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF)` in place of `while(1)`.

Putting these altogether, you can do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
 
int main (void)
{ 
    int ch;

    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if ((ch >= 65) && (ch <= 90)) {
            printf ("%c\n", ch + 32);
        } else if ((ch >= 97) && (ch <= 122)) {
            printf ("%c\n",ch - 32);
        } else if(ch == ';') {
            break;
        }
    }

    /* If loop not terminated due to ';' character 
       then check for EOF and error */
    if (ch != ';') {
        /* Test reason for reaching EOF. */
        if (feof (stdin)) {
            /* if failure caused by end-of-file condition */
            printf ("End of file reached\n");
        } else if (ferror (stdin)) {
            /* if failure caused by some other error */
            perror ("getchar() failed");
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a few issues with your code.

1. You should check for termination `;` *before* you convert the character.
2. You should not hard-code ASCII values; instead use `'a'`, `'z'`, `'A'`, `'Z'`, etc..
3. You should check both upper and lower bounds. This will prevent you from trying to convert the `\n` (newline) character (which is where the `*` comes from: ASCII code for `\n` is `10`, for `*` is `42`).

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It is working fine now.

Comment: @Learner If the answer helped you, upvote it. If it answered your question completely, accept it. We work for browny points here :-)